# pandas aggregate data while carrying a column unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame, a:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2,3,4], 'B': [1,5,3,2,4,1], 'C': [1,4,3,6,1,1]})

   ID  B  C
0   1  1  1
1   1  5  4
2   2  3  3
3   2  2  6
4   3  4  1
5   4  1  1
```

And I want to aggregate it so that the resulting new data frame will be grouped by ID and return the row corresponding to min of B (so apply min() on B and carry C as is.

So the resulting data frame should be:

```
   ID  B  C
0   1  1  1
1   2  2  6
2   3  4  1
3   4  1  1
```

How can I do this programmatically using `pandas.groupby()`, or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sorting before your `groupby`, then taking `first`:

```
a.sort_values('B').groupby('ID',as_index=False).first()

   ID  B  C
0   1  1  1
1   2  2  6
2   3  4  1
3   4  1  1
```

Or, probably a faster way to do it is to sort by `ID` and `B` and then drop duplicate `ID`s, keeping the first (which is the default behavior of `drop_duplicates`):

```
a.sort_values(['ID','B']).drop_duplicates('ID')

   ID  B  C
0   1  1  1
1   2  2  6
2   3  4  1
3   4  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby and transform to filter rows

```
a.loc[a['B'] == a.groupby('ID').B.transform('min')]

    B   C   ID
0   1   1   1
3   2   6   2
4   4   1   3
5   1   1   4
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is sorting involved, and the grouping doesn't involve any calculations, I prefer to work on the underlying `numpy` arrays for performance.

---

Using `argsort` and `numpy.unique`:

```
arr = a.values
out = arr[np.argsort(arr[:, 1])]
_, idx = np.unique(out[:, 0], return_index=True)

out[idx]
```

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 6],
       [3, 4, 1],
       [4, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

To reassign the values to your DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(out[idx], columns=a.columns)
```

```
   ID  B  C
0   1  1  1
1   2  2  6
2   3  4  1
3   4  1  1
```